# Run Pytest in Gitlab-CI as User

Tags: postgresql, docker, pytest, gitlab-ci

I had the following `gitlab-ci.yml` in my python-package repository:

```yaml
image: python:latest

unit-test:
    stage: test
    tags:
        - docker
    script:
        - pip install tox
        - tox

formatting-check:
    stage: test
    tags:
      - docker
    script:
      - pip install black
      - black --check .
```

using this `tox.ini` file:

```ini
[tox]
envlist = my_env

[testenv]
deps =
    -rrequirements.txt
commands =
    python -m pytest tests -s
```

This did work as I wanted it to.

However, then I added tests to test my code against a local Postgresql database using https://pypi.org/project/pytest-postgresql/. For this, I had to install PostgreSQL(`apt -y install postgresql postgresql-contrib libpq5`).

When I added this to my gitlab-ci.yml:

```yaml
image: python:latest

unit-test:
    stage: test
    tags:
        - docker
    script:
        - apt -y install postgresql postgresql-contrib libpq5
        - pip install tox
        - tox

formatting-check:
    stage: test
    tags:
      - docker
    script:
      - pip install black
      - black --check .
```

I got the error from tox, that some module in Postgres (`pg_ctl`) wouldn't allow being run as the root. Log here: https://pastebin.com/fMu1JY5L

So, I must execute tox as a user, not the root.

My first idea was to create a new user (`useradd`) and then switch to that user, but `su` requires inputting a password.

From a quick google search I found out the easiest solution to creating a new user is to create a new Docker Image using Docker-in-Docker.

So, as of now I have this configuration:
`gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
image: docker:19.03.12
services:
  - docker:19.03.12-dind

stages:
  - build
  - test

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG

before_script:
  - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
  - docker info

docker-build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build --pull -t $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE .
    - docker push $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE

formatting-check:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker pull $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE
    - docker run $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE black --check .

unit-test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker pull $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE
    - docker run $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE tox
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:latest
RUN apt update
RUN apt -y install postgresql postgresql-contrib libpq5
RUN useradd -m exec_user
USER exec_user
ENV PATH "$PATH:/home/exec_user/.local/bin"
RUN pip install black tox
```

(I had to add `ENV PATH "$PATH:/home/exec_user/.local/bin"` because `pip` would cry about it not being in the Path)

`tox.ini`:

```ini
[tox]
envlist = my_env

[testenv]
deps =
    -rrequirements.txt
commands =
    python -m pytest tests -s
```

The job `docker-build` completes — the other two fail.

As for `formatting-check`:

```bash
$ docker run $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE black --check .
ERROR: Job failed: execution took longer than 1h0m0s seconds
```

The `black` command usually executes extremely fast (<1s).

As for `unit-test`:

```bash
/bin/sh: eval: line 120: tox: not found
Cleaning up file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 127
```

I have also found, that replacing `docker run $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE tox` with `docker run $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE python3 -m tox` doesn't work. Here, `python3` isn't found (which seems odd given that the base image is `python:latest`).

---

If you have any idea how to solve this issue, let me know :D

Comment: Maybe consider just using [services](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/) in gitlab to run your postgres server instead. Alternatively, using `useradd` should work. Running `su` as root (or using `sudo su - username`) shouldn't require a password.

Comment: `useradd` doesn't work, and I doubt services will work. Services seems to create a new DB for me, but pytest-postgres does create a temporary one for me. The goal is not to use a different DB (also don't know how) (https://pastebin.com/S9i3dpJE)

Comment: I just mean to say that `su` does not require a password when run as root -- as you can see in your job log, it did not stop to ask for password input.

Comment: Oh, your right. I think at one point I made it that it required a password. My bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My first idea was to create a new user (useradd) and then switch to that user, but su requires inputting a password.

This should work for your use case. Running `su` as root will not require a password. You could also use `sudo -u postgres tox` (must `apt install sudo` first).

As a basic working example using `su` (as [seen here](https://gitlab.com/spyoungtech/testproject/-/tree/72558384) - [job](https://gitlab.com/spyoungtech/testproject/-/jobs/2570827534)) using the `postgres` user, which is created automatically when postgres is installed.

```yaml
myjob:
  image: python:3.9-slim
  script:
    - apt update && apt install -y --no-install-recommends libpq-dev postgresql-client postgresql build-essential
    - pip install psycopg2 psycopg pytest pytest-postgresql
    - su postgres -c pytest  
    # or in your case, you might use: su postgres -c tox
```

Alternatively, you might consider just using GitLab's [services feature](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/) to run your postgres server if that's the only obstacle in your way. You can pass `--postgresql-host` and `--postgresql-password` to `pytest` to tell the extension to use the services.